# How do I access the properties of an object which triggered an event?

Tags: plugin-development, events, usermodel

I'm trying my first plug-in; it's to automatically create an entry in a section when a user belonging to a specific user group is activated. However I'm not that hot at PHP and I can't figure out how I would check that the user being activated belongs to a given user group. Here's my basic code from in the main plugin file's init() function:

```php
public function init() {
    craft()->on('users.onActivateUser', function(Event $event) {
        // check the user being activated belongs to the user group 'artist'
        // ???

        // now save an entry on their behalf
        $entry = new EntryModel();
        ...

        $success = craft()->entries->saveEntry($entry);

        if (!$success)
        {
            Craft::log('Couldn’t save the entry "'.$entry->title.'"', LogLevel::Error);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure I need to call isInGroup - but I don't understand what I'm calling that on, or how... $event->isInGroup('artists')?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the context of that event, you will have access to:

```
$event->params['user']
```

... which is:

> [A UserModel instance representing the user that has just been activated.](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#users-onActivateUser)

Once you've got your user model, you can do something like this:

```
$event->params['user']->isInGroup('artists')
```

---

On a separate note, I believe the correct syntax is:

```
craft()->on('users.activateUser' ...
```

You can ditch the "on" in `onActivateUser`. Check out the [official example...](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/hooks-and-events#listening-for-events)